# Python Help - Loops

Tags: python, loops

I hope I may be able to get some help. The point of this program is that it is supposed to take a count of the vowels in a sentence given by the user. I cannot get it to increase the count and everything is staying at zero. I was hoping someone may be able to help show me where I may have messed up the code. It has to stay in a very similar format with the for loop iterating directly over the string. I've tried manipulating it so many different ways. If anyone is able to help I am posting a the code that I have. Thanks!

```
VOWELS = 'AEIOU'
def count3(string, letter):
  count = 0
  # for loop only loops over index, don't initialize or incriminate index
  for char in string:
    #letters = string[char]
    letter_low = str.lower(letter)
    if char == letter_low:
      count = count + 1
  return (letter + " : %d" % count)
  # come back to this, not increasing count of each vowel

def main():
  print("Enter a sentence and this sentence will display its vowel count.")
  sent = input("Enter the sentence to be analyzed:  ")
  while sent:
    print("Your sentence was: " + sent)
    sent_low = str.lower(sent)
    print("\nAnalysis")

  for letter in VOWELS:
    print(count3(sent_low, letter))
```

Comment: I think you want to have your `for` loop inside your `main` function. Also, I think that the `while` loop is going to be infinite, meaning you won't even ever enter the `for letter in VOWELS` loop, and thus won't ever call your `count3` function.

Comment: Wait you just want to find how many vowels are in a sentence?

Comment: The for loop is inside the main function right now, sorry, this is my first time posting and it wouldn't let me just post a pic so the code was all indented incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, I need to find how many vowels are in a sentence, without just calling the count function.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code could use a little cleaning up.

```
def count3(string):
   vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
   count = 0
   for char in string:
      if char in vowels:
         count += 1
   return count
def main():

   sent = input("Enter a sentence and this sentence will display its vowel count:  ")
   print("Your sentence was: " + sent)
   sent_low = sent.lower()
   vowels = count3(sent_low)
   print(f"Your string has {vowels} number of vowels")

main()
```

Comment: That could work, but I guess I should have mentioned that it needed to have the argument, count3(string, letter). Also for the if statement it needs to be char == letter which then adds to the count.

Comment: Why does it **need** to be char==letter? Also what would letter be?

Answer (score 0):

What if you used the `.count()` method?

```
def count3(string):
    count = 0
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    string_as_list = list(string.lower())
    for vowel in vowels:
        count += string_as_list.count(vowel)
    return count

def main():
    while True:
        print("Enter a sentence and this sentence will display its vowel count.")
        sent = input("Enter the sentence to be analyzed:  ")
        print(count3(sent))
    return None


main()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use the .count() method. I need to write a function that does the counting. It has to be a for loop iterating directly in the string. The count3 function must also be def count3(string, letter):

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me after I remove the `while` statement, which was causing an infinite loop.

```py
# Exactly the same as your code, with the while statement removed

VOWELS = 'AEIOU'


def count3(string, letter):
    count = 0
    # for loop only loops over index, don't initialize or incriminate index
    for char in string:
        # letters = string[char]
        letter_low = str.lower(letter)
        if char == letter_low:
            count = count + 1
    return (letter + " : %d" % count)
    # come back to this, not increasing count of each vowel


def main():
    print("Enter a sentence and this sentence will display its vowel count.")
    sent = input("Enter the sentence to be analyzed:  ")

    print("Your sentence was: " + sent)
    sent_low = str.lower(sent)
    print("\nAnalysis")

    for letter in VOWELS:
        print(count3(sent_low, letter))


### Example output if I run main() and enter "this is a test string"
# Analysis
# A : 1
# E : 1
# I : 3
# O : 0
# U : 0
```

HOWEVER... There are better ways to do what you're trying to accomplish. For example, here's how you could leverage the `.count()` method. This produces the same result as your code while eliminating the for loop.

```py
def count_occurrences(string, letter):
    return string.lower().count(letter.lower())


def main():
    print("Enter a sentence and this sentence will display its vowel count.")
    sent = input("Enter the sentence to be analyzed:  ")

    print("Your sentence was: " + sent)

    for letter in VOWELS:
        count = count_occurrences(sent, letter)
        print(f"{letter}: {count}")
```

If you insist on not using the `.count()` method, you can still simplify your code. For example:

```py
def count_occurrences(string, letter):
    return len([x for x in string if x.lower() == letter.lower()])
```